# Why do I get "Class "Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy" does not exist" when I install Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I started to install Magento. This is the command line instruction:

```
"php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/magento" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="user@example.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"
```

When I execute it, I have this error:

```
Class "Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy" does not exist
```

How can I reslove this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This error is coming when there is some permission related issue, so try to provide appropriate permissions to Magento folder & files.

For permission cmd, you can follow below commands :

```
cd <your Magento install dir> 

// 644 permission for files
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; 
                   
// 755 permission for directory
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;    

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R :<web server group> .

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after updating to Magento 2.4.4. I fixed it by running:

```bash
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was php version issue.

I was running command

```
php bin/magento s:up
```

which give me below error

```
Class "Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy" does not exist
```

because my default php version was set 8.0 for command line so i need to use

```
/usr/bin/php7.4 bin/magento s:up
```